# Convert (MultiIndex) Dataframe to a list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi index dataframe:

```
                       C
 A         B
25        58        16.0
          59       135.0
          60        36.0
```

which I want to convert to a list of dicts/objects:

```
[
     {A: 25, B: 58, C: 16},
     {A: 25, B: 59, C: 135},
     {A: 25, B: 60, C: 36}
]
```

I am able to reset the index `df.reset_index`:

```
           A        B      C
0         25       58   16.0
1         25       59  135.0
2         25       60   36.0
```

and use `df.to_dict('index')` to get this:

```
[
     {0: {A: 25, B: 58, C: 16}},
     {1: {A: 25, B: 59, C: 135}},
     {2: {A: 25, B: 60, C: 36}}
]
```

which is close, but I don't want to include the index in the resulting dict.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [**`to_dict`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `records`

```
df.reset_index().to_dict('records')

[{'A': 25.0, 'B': 58.0, 'C': 16.0},
 {'A': 25.0, 'B': 59.0, 'C': 135.0},
 {'A': 25.0, 'B': 60.0, 'C': 36.0}]
```

Comment: Ha. I had tried `list` from [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and for some reason never saw `records`. That's fixed it.